# Passing a list of variables to a function and filter in for loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have a dataframe (sample below) and I want to filter it based on a list of variables and values in a function.

I have a sample dataframe as below

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b", "c"), x2 = c("d", "e", "f"), 
                 x3 = c("g", "h", "i"), x4 = c("j", "k", "l"),
                 x5 = c("m", "n", "o"), x6 = c("p", "q", "r"))

Variable <- list(x1, x3, x4, x6)

Value <- list("c", "g", "k|j", "r")
```

I want to pass this list to a function to generalize the filter. I have created the below function

```
NewFun <- function(dataset, variable, value){

  for (i in 1:length(variable)){
    variable <- variable[i]
    value <- value[i]
    
    get(dataset) %>% filter(UQ(sym(variable[i])) %in% {{value[i]}})
  }
}
```

but I get this error

```
Error in `sym()`:
! Can't convert a list to a symbol.
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach which works. Rather than using `dplyr::filter()`, it uses `grepl()` and indexing to work with your regular expressions (I.e., "k|j") in a new function `my_filter()`. We then apply each the `Variables` and the `Values` using `purrr::map2()`

Note, to do it this way, I've referred to the `Variable`s as strings in character vectors.

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b", "c"), x2 = c("d", "e", "f"), 
                 x3 = c("g", "h", "i"), x4 = c("j", "k", "l"),
                 x5 = c("m", "n", "o"), x6 = c("p", "q", "r"))

Variable <- c("x1", "x3", "x4", "x6")
Value <- c("c", "g", "k|j", "r")

my_filter <- function(df, var, val) {
  df[grepl(val, df[[var]]),]
}

purrr::map2(.x = Variable, .y = Value, .f = my_filter, df = df)

[[1]]
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
3  c  f  i  l  o  r

[[2]]
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  a  d  g  j  m  p

[[3]]
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  a  d  g  j  m  p
2  b  e  h  k  n  q

[[4]]
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
```

This gives you a list of dataframes which you can then use separately, or if you want to combine them with AND or OR logic you could easily do that with things like bind_rows() reduce(), duplicated() etc.

Comment: Thank you Josh, this works but I wanted this single function to be utilized in another function. Thanks again